# Load JavaScript from a post that's loading into Fancybox via ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript

I'm hoping this makes sense. When a user clicks on a post title I'm launching a modal overlay via fancybox, and feeding the associated post content via ajax. However I have a javascript call function that I need to run that is from the post that isn't running when the content is pulled. I have a guess the it has something to do with $(document).ready(function()  Any ideas? How to I load this function after the modal overlay has been triggered?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v",
        ogv: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/ogv/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.ogv",
        poster: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/poster/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.png"
      });
    },
    swfPath: "/js",
    supplied: "m4v, ogv",
                        size: {
                     width: "850px",
                     height: "438px"
                }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply any javascript after the content is loaded. [See the Callbacks tab in documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs).

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function(current, previous){
        // initialize your js stuff  
    }
});
```